# Issue with loading and caching retina images for UIImageView animation

Tags: uiimageview, retina-display, uiviewanimation

**What I have**

For my game I'm creating several animations using view.animationImages = imagesArray; [view startAnimating];

**In my animation helper class I use this**

```
- (UIImage *)loadRetinaImageIfAvailable:(NSString *)path
{
    NSString *retinaPath = [[path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@2x.%@", [[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension], [path pathExtension]]];

    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0 && [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:retinaPath] == YES)
        return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:retinaPath]] CGImage] scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    else
        return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
}

- (NSMutableArray *)generateCachedImageArrayWithFilename:(NSString *)filename extension:(NSString *)extension andImageCount:(int)count
{
    _imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _fileExtension = extension;
    _imageName = filename;
    _imageCount = count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        NSString *tempImageNames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i", filename, i];
        NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:tempImageNames ofType:extension];

        UIImage *frameImage = [self loadRetinaImageIfAvailable:imagePath];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frameImage.size);
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameImage.size.width, frameImage.size.height);
        [frameImage drawInRect:rect];
        UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [_imagesArray addObject:renderedImage];

        if (_isDoublingFrames)
        {
            [_imagesArray addObject:renderedImage];
        }
        else if (_isTriplingFrames)
        {
            [_imagesArray addObject:renderedImage];
            [_imagesArray addObject:renderedImage];
        }

        NSLog(@"filename = %@", filename);
    }

    return _imagesArray;
}
```

**Problem and facts**

- Without caching images I got retina versions of images byt my animations are not fluent
- If I cache images this way, animations are ok, but uses non-retina versions of images

Please is there some other way to cache and get retina versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these images located in your application bundle? If so this logic is all unnecessary because the imageWithContentsOfFile: method will already detect and load the @2x image on a retina device.

Also, you'd be better off using the [UIImage imageNamed:] method instead because this automatically caches the image for re-use, and decompresses it immediately, avoiding the need for manually caching the images, or for that trickery with drawing it into an offscreen CGContext.

Comment: Yes, all images are in app bundle. Hm, that with imageNamed is interesting because I somewhere read the opposite :/ Therefore I used this crazy CGContext stuff.

Comment: I'm also using for all images http://imageoptim.com with project Compress PNG Files set to NO.

Comment: Fwiw, Apple advise against disabling compress PNG files in Xcode. It performs additional optimisations that ImageOptim doesn't, such as byte swapping, so even though the images will be larger, they'll load and display quicker.

Comment: I think I see why you're getting non-retina images. Instead of UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions and pass 0 as the scale parameter (that way it will match the device screen scale).

Comment: Thats interesting with this ImageOptim. I really like it because it makes my pngs like 10-50%smaller and I'm working on bigger game where I handle with lot of pngs. 

What about using imageoptim and enabling PNG compress to ON?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using ImageOptim, but you should leave Xcode's optimisations enabled as well (this is mentioned in one of the WWDC graphics performance videos).

Comment: Thanks Nick for great info !