# Is there a simple and elegant solution to put UIView animation(animating pngs) from processing with CPU to GPU?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, gpu, uiviewanimation

In my app I'm using lot of UIView animations (animating pngs).
Is there a simple and elegant solution to put all this UIView image animation from processing with CPU to GPU? It's worth it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animated PNG sequences are already drawn by the GPU (the actual image loading and conversion to OpenGL textures is done by CPU, but drawing the images is done by the GPU).

If you are having performance problems, the bottleneck is probably in the loading or decompressing of the images, in which case there are a few options, such as combining them into a single spritesheet and then animating them by assigning the image as your view.layer.contents and moving the view.layer.contentsRect around to select each frame in turn using a CAKeyframeAnimation.

Alternatively, I have written a library that can load and play a PVRTC image sequence in real time using a UIView subclass that mirrors that UIImageView API, but does all of the drawing using OpenGL. This is much more CPU and memory-friendly than using PNGs, and may solve your performance problems (assuming you actually have any).

Check it out: https://github.com/nicklockwood/GLView

(there's an example of smoothly playing a large PVR image sequence included in the examples folder, along with instructions for batch-converting PNG images to PVR).

Comment: We can say there's no problem with performance rather with loading the pictures on retina iPad 3.Please take a look at my 2nd post on stack where you can find what am I doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427908/issue-with-loading-and-caching-retina-images-for-uiimageview-animation
I looked at your GLView and it's very nice and will use it next project. For now I don't want to recreate all my logic in the game I've already done.

Comment: Loading and drawing images on a retina iPad is inherently slow due to their sheer size and the under-specced GPU. My advice is to load standard-def images for anything that moves, then swap in the retina image when the image stops moving (e.g. for an animation sequence this would mean that only the final frame needs to be retina quality).

Comment: Yes you are right. Btw this solution is VERY elegant! I don't have static picures in the end of animation, but I can use it also very well on array of idle state animation pictures. Nice :)